# Issue aligning boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website to help with learning web development, pretty much a place where I can put my notes. At the moment, I am trying to make two boxes for examples (1. code example, 2. site example), but the boxes aren't aligning and I cant figure out why.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Programming Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#html">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#css">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="content">
        <div id="html" class="tabcontent">
            <div class="body">
                <div class="border">
                    <div class="section">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h1>Discovering&nbsp;HTML&nbsp;and&nbsp;Tags</h1>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="info">
                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: -10px;">What is HTML?</h3>
                            <p>Html is a computer markup language that structures all the webpages on the internet. HTML stands for Hypertext Markup Language.</p>
                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: -10px;">HTML Tags</h3>
                            <p>All tags start with &lt, followed by a keyword, and end with &gt. Tags like &ltbutton&gt are opening tags, to finish creating a button element we need text, and a closing tag, we can make and a closing tag by adding a / to another tag, and then write what we want in between them.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="example">
                            <div class="code-example">we</div>
                            <div class="site-example">bust</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info">
                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: -10px;">Text and Headings</h3>
                            <p>We can create headings in HTML to emphasize certain texts. There are 6 sizes of headings in HTML, from h1 to h6.</p>
                            <p>In HTML, the keywords of some tags are obvious, but there are other tags that use a shortened form. For example, we use the &ltp&gt tag for a paragraph. Coding a paragraph is similar to coding a button. You need an opening tag, followed by your text, and a closing tag.</p>
                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: -10px;">Web Page Structuring</h3>
                            <p>An element is what we call the opening tag, closing tag, and code in between.</p>
                            <p>To create a webpage, you&#8217ll need an opening and closing HTML tag.</p>
                            <p>An element is what we call the opening tag, closing tag, and code in between.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div class="border">
                    <div class="section">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h1>Structuring&nbsp;Text&nbsp;with&nbsp;Tags</h1>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="info">
                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: -10px;">Line Breaks, Emphasis, and Importance</h3>
                            <p>Sometimes we can format paragraphs with line breaks, we can do this with the line break tag: &ltbr&gt</p>
                            <h3>Head, Title, and Doctype</h3>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="css" class="tabcontent">
            <div class="body">
                <div class="border">
                    <div class="section">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h1>Styling With CSS</h1>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="info">
                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: -10px;">What&nbsp;is&nbsp;CSS?</h3>
                            <p>CSS (or Cascading Style Sheets) is a programming language used for describing the presentation of a document written in markup languages like HTML.</p>
                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: -10px;">Inline Style</h3>
                            <p>Html is a computer markup language that structures all the webpages on the internet. HTML stands for Hypertext Markup Language.</p>
                            <h3 style="margin-bottom: -10px;">Font Properties</h3>
                            <p>All tags start with &lt, followed by a keyword, and end with &gt. Tags like &ltbutton&gt are opening tags, to finish creating a button element we need text, and a closing tag, we can make and a closing tag by adding a / to another tag, and then write what we want in between them.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="javascript" class="tabcontent">
            <h2>JavaScript Notes</h2>
            <!-- JavaScript notes content goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url(/background-wood.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: white;
    font-family: ComicStory;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
    font-family: ComicStory;
    font-size: vmin;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden; /* Prevent vertical scrolling */
}
@font-face {
    font-family: ComicStory;
    src: url(/Comic\ Story.ttf);
}

hr {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    height: 8px;
    width: 80%;
}

.border {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 120px 2px black;
    max-width: 900px;
    background: url(chalkboard-border.png);
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 28px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

.section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-image: url(chalkboard.png);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto; /* Set height to auto */
}

.example {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
}

.code-example {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    align-self:first baseline;
    margin-block: 0;
}

.site-example {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    align-self:first baseline;
    margin-block: 0;
}

.header {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: -20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.info {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-inline: 20px;
}

header {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

nav {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav li {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(92, 92, 92);
}

nav a.selected {
    background-color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
    color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      font-size: 3.5vw; /* Adjust the font size for mobile */
    }
  
    .button {
      width: 90%;
      height: 150px;
    }
  
    .border {
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
      width: 90%;
    }
  
    .header {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      font-size: 70%;
    }

    .info {
      margin: 10px; /* Adjust the margin for better spacing */
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent");
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");

    // Function to show selected tab and hide others
    function showTabContent(tabId) {
        tabs.forEach(tab => {
            if (tab.id === tabId) {
                tab.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                tab.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    }

    // Add click event listeners to navigation links
    navLinks.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const tabId = this.getAttribute("href").substring(1);
            showTabContent(tabId);
            navLinks.forEach(navLink => {
                navLink.classList.remove("selected");
            });
            this.classList.add("selected");
        });
    });

    // Show the initial tab
    showTabContent(tabs[0].id);
    navLinks[0].classList.add("selected");
});
```

[Here is what the site looks like atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeU0z.jpg)

I tried messing with the padding and margin but nothing I do works.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The code in the question gives this result, which does not show misalignment: https://jsfiddle.net/8vhebo07/

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the issue you have lies in the CSS styling of the example boxes. The `align-self:first baseline;` property I think is not valid. To align the boxes properly, you can modify the CSS for the `.example, .code-example, and .site-example` Try this out

```
.example {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-start; /* Align items at the top */
}

.code-example {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-example {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I hope it solve the issue

Comment: `align-self:first baseline;` is valid but that is what is causing the issue. There's no need to declare the alignment at all according to my testing. I was just about to post this answer as well.

Comment: Looks like that was the issue, thank you for the help.